# Return previous line with Findstr

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I am running `FINDSTR` command to find specific text in .txt files. I want to print matching lines as well as 1 previous line.

```
findstr "ActualStartDate:"  * > a.txt
```

if my file is like this

```
abcd  
defg  
cds  
ActualStartDate: invalid date
```

Result should be like this

```
cds  
ActualStartDate: invalid date
```

Comment: yeah,while using FINDSTR i can print only matching line but i also need line which comes before matching string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this with [grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm):

```
grep -1 "ActualStartDate:" *.txt
```

output is eg.:

```
file.txt-cds
file.txt:ActualStartDate: invalid date
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool written as a batch file that can do this easily, which uses built in Windows scripting.

findrepl.bat - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697